# How is an iterable created when the first argument to sum includes a for loop?

Tags: python, iterable

The [Python documentation for sum](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) shows that an iterable has to be passed in as the first argument for `sum`.

I was solving this leetcode problem [1295. Find Numbers with Even Number of Digits](https://leetcode.com/problems/find-numbers-with-even-number-of-digits/)
:

> Given an array nums of integers, return how many of them contain an even number of digits.

I was solving this the long way like this:

```
# # longer as in more lines of code
class Solution:
    def findNumbers(self, nums: List[int]) -> int:
        count = 0

        for num in nums:
            if len(str(num)) % 2 == 0:
                count += 1

        return count
```

but decided to look at the other suggested answers to see if I missed something. One never knows with Easy questions on Leetcode. That's when I ran into [this line of code](https://leetcode.com/problems/find-numbers-with-even-number-of-digits/discuss/468107/Python-3-lightning-fast-one-line-solution/632254) that made me wonder if I understood what was going on.

```
from typing import List
# one line solution
class Solution:
    def findNumbers(self, nums: List[int]) -> int:
        return sum(len(str(num)) %2 == 0 for num in nums)
```

Could someone clarify how "future" booleans lead to an iterable? Is a list being created from the for loop?

Comment: The crucial thing that makes this magic work is the fact that `True == 1` (try it).  If you sum an iterable of booleans, you therefore get a count of the `True` values.

Answer (score 1):

That's not something special to `sum`. `len(str(num)) %2 == 0 for num in nums` is a [generator expression](https://peps.python.org/pep-0289/), it's like list comprehension but does not create a list. Instead an iterator that calculates values on demand when they're needed.

Notice that replacing the generator expression with a list comprehension gives the same result:

```
        return sum([len(str(num)) %2 == 0 for num in nums])
```

But leads to more memory usage.

Then there is what Samwise mentioned, `True == 1` and `False == 0`. You can change your code to use this fact

```
class Solution:
    def findNumbers(self, nums: List[int]) -> int:
        count = 0

        for num in nums:
            count += len(str(num)) % 2 == 0

        return count
```

Answer (score 0):

The `... for ...` expression inside the `sum()` is a grammar sugar to create annoymous generator in python (see [here](https://peps.python.org/pep-0289/) for more details). The equlivent code shall be

```py
def f(num):
    for num in nums:
       yield len(str(num)) %2 == 0

class Solution:
    def findNumbers(self, nums: List[int]) -> int:
        return sum(f(nums))
```